# Spark creates new row when reading in CSV with line break in text

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

So, this issue has been talked about quite a bit, but it was supposed to be fixed in Spark 2.2.0 which was just released. From what I can tell, the `wholeLine` option is supposed to fix this issue, however I am having no luck. The issue is that when there is a line break in a value, say like, a notes column that has a bunch of text in it, and there's a line break in those notes, Spark treats it as a new row.

Here is the snippet I'm using to read the data from the CSV.

```
sparkSession.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .option("wholeFile", "true")
  .option("quoteMode", "ALL")
  .option("parserLib", "univocity")
  .csv(csvFilePath)
```

As you can tell, I'm using every option under the sun, but I'm still getting the wrong output. The output I get is below, those are all supposed to be unique integers, but they're being polluted with data from other columns, from another row. I've changed the data a little but you can see there is string data in the column with the IDs.

```
+--------------------+
|                  ID|
+--------------------+
|             3876849|
|             3876872|
|          consistent|
|                4/30|
|,blah blah blah  ...|
|             3876876|
|             3876878|
|       5-6 days ago"|
|             3876879|
|             3876880|
|blah blah blah bl...|
|             3876893|
|*blah blah blah  ...|
|             3876900|
|             3876904|
+--------------------+
```

This has me really stumped, for good measure I'm including my build.sbt as well.

```
name := "MyApp"
organization := "com.test"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.5.0",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" %"2.8.2"
)
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

Comment: So...what's the problem you're trying to solve? Can you show the output that does not meet your requirements?

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot to mention that.

Comment: can you also show the input?